# Triggering a Visual Studio build from a Linux Host

Tags: linux, windows, msbuild

I am starting work on a very Windows-specific project, but I am much more familiar with a Linux development environment (ie, emacs and zsh).

All I need to do with my Windows code is compile it - I have a network share on which I can edit the code, and I can deal with viewing the logs remotely with tail.

Is there any way I can trigger a build on a Windows server remotely?

On Linux this is trivial - simply remotely execute your build script via SSH, or use Jenkins or some other CI to trigger the build through a web interface.

I'm really wondering whether there is some sort of functionality I am missing with Windows that would allow me to run "MsBuild.exe" or "cl.exe" from a separate Linux host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you probably want to run a SSH server on windows. [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows) has a few options, you should then be able to invoke msbuild from the command line.

Comment: Oh, that works perfect - exactly what I was looking for. I had played around with psexec/winexe but couldn't get them to do what I wanted.

Comment: If you wanted to go crazy you could also try Cygwin or services for unix. But a simple server should do the trick. Psexec is cool but I've never tried it from *nix

Comment: Nah, this works perfectly. If I need to later on I'll probably end up playing around with Cygwin but for now this does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can build most any project via command line.

I've included a link to one resource I found. There are many. Just search "compile [your project type] command line"

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0da142c9-9373-4459-aa41-9af597accfc5/compile-c-project-with-command-line-

Comment: I know how to trigger command-line builds, I am wondering how to trigger them remotely from a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free version of [DameWare NT Utilities](http://www.dameware.com/) to issue remote commands on the command-line to trigger the build.  They have a "Remote Command" feature which is very helpful.  Also, if you want to be more hard-core, you can set up a Team Foundation Server and trigger builds remotely using a build script, but that is a bit much more work and probably not worth it.